# This solution contains no resources scoped for a web application

Tags: solution-package, solution

I'm trying to figure out exactly how I can deploy a solution to a single web application without it being deployed to other web applications in the same farm.

The reason for this is that I have different customers each with their own web application in my farm, but I don't want the same solution shared with all the other web applications.

So I've heard some guys suggest using sandboxed solutions, but then others say that sandboxed solutions have certain limitations they can't accept. What exactly are these limitations with sandboxed solutions?

So now I tried the following to deploy a dummy solution I created.

```
Add-SPSolution -c:/mywebpart.wsp

Install-SPSolution mywebpart.wsp -WebApplication "SharePoint Debugging" -GacDeployment
```

And I get the error : This solution contains no resources scoped for a web application.

So what can I do to have my solution deployed to a single web application?

Comment: Call me a rogue and a scofflaw, but I wasn't able to leave a comment, so am trying to post in the "Answers" section: I already have a SafeControl entry (I didn't add it, at least not explicitly), and I am getting this err msg. Here is what I've got (bogus PublicKeyToken): <Assemblies> <Assembly Location="PostTravelWizard.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache"> <SafeControls> <SafeControl Assembly="PostTravelWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b52AndBombedEmWithTheBlooz" Namespace="PostTravelWizard.PostTravelWizardWebPart" TypeName="*" /> </SafeControls> </Assembly> </

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open your manifest file of Package

2)  (+ Edit Options) Expand it. Click on Overwrite generated XML and edit manifest in the XML editor link. > Edit manifest in the XML editor.

3)  In Edit mode  node look like.

```
<Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="SharePointProject1.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
</Assemblies>
```

4) Just add dummy SafeControl to the Assembly node.

Comment: After doing this and packaging the solution again and removing the old solution and re-adding the new one - I don't see the solution in either one of the following under site settings : "Web Parts Gallery", "Site Features", "Site Collection Features".

Comment: Did you see that your solution deployed in central administration?

Comment: Central Administration > System Settings > Farm Management > Manage Farm Solutions.

Comment: Yes it's there. And it shows that it is deployed to the web application I specified. But I don't see it in that web application's site.

Comment: Check that all items from your solution exists in 14 hive folder. And check Logs in 14 hive folder.

Comment: I checked and it's actually not in the hive folder. What should I do to get it there?

Comment: This may be in case if your web part or artifacts not added in features or you do something wrong with package file

Comment: I recreated another dummy application - this time using a farm solution instead of a sandboxed solution. Created a simple Visual Web Part in the solution and used the same steps to install the solution to the web application. This time around the solution files are in the hive and I can also activate the feature from the "site collection features" page. But... the feature is also available in my other web applications feature lists. I want it to be only for a single web application.

Comment: Now you must check that the safe control entries exist only in web.config for a specific web application. Like in the post.

Comment: This [blog](http://sharedpointers.blogspot.com/2011/03/deploying-solutions-to-specific-web.html) has an example of how to add a dummy Safe Control.

Comment: whats the meaning of "just add dummy safecontrol to assmebly node" ? can you pls elaborate .

Comment: i got this error when add a dummy sp dll into the package.package fileError 1 Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot find this file specified in the manifest file: DummySharePointProject1.dll
  0 0